# Drawing an assembled image to the JPanel

Tags: java, swing, graphics, bufferedimage, paintcomponent

I am working on a program that I can use to present topics in front of my class. While MS Powerpoint and similar programs are nice, I feel like they are lacking in some areas. I am not trying to re-create these programs, I am only trying to make a program where I can type text into String arrays, add images, and position them all on the screen.

Currently my program opens a fullscreen dark window with a little X in the top left, which when clicked will close the program.

Here is the class file:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Main {

    static JFrame frame;
    static MyPanel panel;
    static MouseListener listener;

    static final int letterWidth = 6;
    static final int letterHeight = 9;
    static final int letterRow = 10;
    static final int letterCol = 11;
    static final int letterNum = 110;

    static String[] textA = {"Hello World,",
                "Here is a test",
                "of what I can do.",
                "Isn't it neat?!"
                };
    static int textX = 100;
        static int textY = 100;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Welcome to Presenter");
        System.out.println("Beginning loading");
        frame = new JFrame();
        panel = new MyPanel();

        listener = new MouseListener(){
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                if(arg0.getButton() ==MouseEvent.BUTTON1){

                        //Close button
                    int x = (int) MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getX();
                        int y = (int) MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getY();
                    if(x>20 && x<48 && y>20 && y<56){
                        frame.dispose();
                            System.exit(0);
                    }


                }
             }

            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {}

            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {}

            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {}

            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {}
        };


        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setFocusable(true);
        frame.add(panel);
            frame.addMouseListener(listener);
            System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Loading Complete");
    }



public static class MyPanel extends JPanel{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    HashMap<String, BufferedImage> iLetters;
    static BufferedImage exitButton = new BufferedImage(28, 36, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    static BufferedImage letters = new BufferedImage(120, 198, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Scanner lightbulb;
    static boolean point = false;
    int x;
    int y;
    BufferedImage textBox;
    int boxW, boxH;

    public MyPanel(){
        //pictures
        File a = new File("Exit.png");
        try { exitButton = ImageIO.read(a); } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        a = new File("Letters.png");
        try { letters = ImageIO.read(a); } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        //letter index
        try { lightbulb = new Scanner(new File("letters.txt")); } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

        System.out.println("Files Read");



        //create letters
        System.out.println("Beginning tiling");
        iLetters = new HashMap<String, BufferedImage>();
        BufferedImage[] pics = new BufferedImage[letterNum];
        int count = 0;
        for(int x=0; x<letterCol; x++){
            for(int y=0; y<letterRow; y++){
                pics[count] = new BufferedImage(letterWidth, letterHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

                Graphics2D gr = pics[count++].createGraphics();
                gr.drawImage(letters, 0, 0, letterWidth, letterHeight, letterWidth * y, letterHeight * x, letterWidth * y + letterWidth, letterHeight * x + letterHeight, null);
                gr.dispose();
            }
            System.out.println("Row " + x + " tiled.");
        }
        System.out.println("Completed Tiling");

        System.out.println("Beginning indexing");
        int loc = 0;
        String key = "";
        while(lightbulb.hasNext()){
            loc = lightbulb.nextInt()-1;
            key = lightbulb.next();
            iLetters.put(key, pics[loc]);
        }
        System.out.println("Indexing Complete");

        System.out.println("Making Text Boxes");
        makeTextBox(textA);

        System.out.println("Text Boxes Made");

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        this.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 10));
        g.drawImage(exitButton, 20, 20, null);
//          g.drawImage(iLetters.get("A"), 100, 100, null);
        drawTexts(g);
    }

    public void drawTexts(Graphics g){
        g.drawImage(textBox, textX, textY, textX+(boxW*2), textY+(boxH*2), null);
    }

    public int findLongest(String[] text){
        int longest = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<text.length; i++){
            if(text[i].length() > longest)
            longest = text[i].length();
        }
        return longest;
    }

    public void makeTextBox(String[] text){
        int longest = findLongest(text);
        boxW = (longest*6)+(longest-1);
        boxH = (text.length*9)+(text.length-1);
        textBox = new BufferedImage(boxW, boxH, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2d = textBox.createGraphics();
        char[] line;
        int drawX = 0;
        int drawY = 0;


        for(int i=0; i<text.length; i++){
            line = text[i].toCharArray();
            for(int j=0; j<line.length; j++){
                if(j<line.length-1){
                    g2d.drawImage(iLetters.get(line[j]), drawX, drawY, null);
                    drawX += letterWidth + 1;
                }
                else{
                    g2d.drawImage(iLetters.get(line[j]), drawX, drawY, null);
                }
            }
            if(i<text.length-1){
                drawY += letterHeight + 1;
            }
            else{
                drawY += letterHeight;
            }
        }
        g2d.dispose();
    }






}

}
```

The rest of the files needed for it to run are here http://www.mediafire.com/?jq8vi4dm3t4b6

2 PNGs and 1 text file.

The program runs fine with no errors. The only problem is the drawTexts() method. When the method is called, the lines of text do not appear anywhere on screen, when they should be appearing at (100, 100) at 2x the size of the letters in the file.

It's been a while since I did graphics. I remember needing to call repaint() somewhere, but I cannot remember if I need it here, and if I do, where it goes.

Comment: I don't think you understand what `drawImage(Image img, int dx1, int dy1, int dx2, int dy2, int sx1, int sy1, int sx2, int sy2, ImageObserver observer)` actually does

Comment: you're right, I don't. I'll go find out.
Edit: now I understand what that does

Comment: Take a look at `BufferedImage#getSubImage`, I think it will do what you're trying to do ;)

Comment: Oh that's much cleaner thank you

Comment: That created new errors. I'l try to work through them but for now i'm not sure if that solves my original problem

Comment: There are 10 columns and 11 rows, not the other way round...

Comment: `while (lightbulb.hasNext()) {` never seems to loop...

Comment: There should be 10 rows, like in the png... right? That part looped for me... at least, i got it to fill the console with 0-109 Edit: i guess it is 11 rows... looks like i flipped some stuff around

Comment: It depends, are you reading the last 2 characters?

Comment: 110 un1? it read that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this might take some time...

[image: Letters]

There are 10 columns and 11 rows, these are around the wrong way...

```
static final int letterRow = 10;
static final int letterCol = 11;
```

I don't think you understand what `gr.drawImage(letters, 0, 0, letterWidth, letterHeight, letterWidth * y, letterHeight * x, letterWidth * y + letterWidth, letterHeight * x + letterHeight, null);` is actually doing, what you really want is `BufferedImage#getSubImage`...

```
BufferedImage subimage = letters.getSubimage(letterWidth * x, letterHeight * y, letterWidth, letterHeight);
```

You're reading the `Letters.png` file in row/column order, but building the mapping as if it was in column/row order...

Instead of...

```
for (int x = 0; x < letterCol; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < letterRow; y++) {
```

You should be using...

```
for (int y = 0; y < letterRow; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < letterCol; x++) {
```

The `lightbulb` `Scanner` is not reading the file...I'm don't use `Scanner` that often, but when I changed it to `lightbulb = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("letters.txt")));` it worked...

In your `makeTextBox` method you are trying to retrieve the image using a `char` instead of `String`, this means the lookup fails as the two keys are incompatible.  You need to use something more like...

```
BufferedImage img = iLetters.get(Character.toString(line[j]));
```

Also, on each new line, you are not resting the `drawX` variable, so the text just keeps running off...In fact, I just re-wrote the loop to look more like...

```
for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    line = text[i].toCharArray();
    for (int j = 0; j < line.length; j++) {
        BufferedImage img = iLetters.get(Character.toString(line[j]));
        g2d.drawImage(img, drawX, drawY, null);
        if (j < line.length - 1) {
            drawX += letterWidth + 1;
        }
    }
    drawX = 0;
    if (i < text.length - 1) {
        drawY += letterHeight + 1;
    } else {
        drawY += letterHeight;
    }
}
```

And yes, it could be simplified more, but little steps...

There might be a bunch of other things, but that should get you a step closer...

Comment: I changed the `drawImage()` to the `letters.getSubimage()`, and now i'm getting the error `Exception in thread "main" java.awt.image.RasterFormatException: (x + width) is outside of Raster
 at sun.awt.image.ByteInterleavedRaster.createWritableChild(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getSubimage(Unknown Source)
 at Main$MyPanel.<init>(Main.java:117)
 at Main.main(Main.java:43)`, when it worked before and printed individual characters when I asked it to. I changed it back and now it prints properly. I'll see if I can get `getSubimage()` to work, but if not I'll stick with the other

Comment: I changed a lot of stuff, might have missed something...Make sure you've updated the `letterRow` and `letterCol` values correctly ;)

Comment: I got it to work! http://puu.sh/8jWX9/09514938cb.png the only issue now is that the text cuts off on the right and bottom

Comment: I'm using your loop. also, I changed the drawImage() in drawTexts to `g.drawImage(textBox, textX, textY,(boxW)*2,(boxH)*2, null);`, which removed the odd way the text was distorting. Edit: that change fixed the problem for me